# MySQL 5.5 InnoDB = OFF?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

We run a server with MySQL 5.5. 95% of the tables are set to the InnoDB engine.

However whenever I look at the my.ini file (using the MySQL Workbench) under mysqld section innodb is unchecked and OFF is selected in the drop down. I don't see this line added to the my.ini file when viewing with notepad.

Should I check this setting and set it to ON so we can utilize the enabled innodb settings (buffers & log file etc.) or does this not matter?

Thanks

Comment: Currently if you download mysql 5.5.19 RPM's (source included) for linux generic INNODB is not available. Inspecting source RPM file WITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE is not on. **[SOLVED] No InnoDb was caused my invalid innodb files due to changing innodb related files settings (on my.cnf) with the server running.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with MySQL Workbench.

MySQL 5.5 has a default storage engine of InnoDB.

In fact, the option [default_storage_engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine) is predefined as follows:

- MySQL 5.5.4 and prior, MyISAM
- MySQL 5.5.8 and after, InnoDB

There is another option called [storage-engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_storage_engine), which was deprecated as for MySQL 5.5.3. Keep in mind that MySQL 5.5.8 was the very first GA release.

I would strongly suspect MySQL Workbench if it is coded to check `storage-engine` instead of `default-storage-engine`. This would allow MySQL Workbench to monitor older release of MySQL.